# Elasticsearch exporting documents by batch in some time interval

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do export documents from elasticsearch with pagination or scroll API.

My problem is I want to export my documents in some interval let's say 2 minute.

Export documents, wait 2 min and export the next batch, wait 2 min again and so on..

I know that I am able to do with scrollId and also pagination with a sorted documents. In pagination I have page + size = 10.000 limit so I don't want to use because of limits.

So I want to continue with scroll api but I have one more problem too. This should be cancellable. After exporting some documents I want to cancel my export job and wait 5-6 hours let's say or tomorrow I want to start my export again. I know that my connection is closed and I don't know the limit of the scroll time. If I am able to do that is opening connection a good idea for statefull operation ? I think it is not. My question is can I use scrollId after tomorrow for example ?

Question 2: After a researched I have find out search after (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after). Am I able to use this for saving to db and continue after x hours after.

Thanks !!

Comment: If you are exporting I would go with scroll context.  You can cancel it whenever you want.  I don't really understand why you can't use it?

Comment: I can cancel ok but restart where it stopped. That is where my problem starts. :/

Comment: No, you cannot restart a scroll context once you cancel.  It takes resources to keep the scroll context alive.  Think of it as a in-memory snapshot at the time of start.  Why can't you export it all at once?

Comment: Beucase user want to stop export processing at some time and continue after a time, think like a push notification processing